# Weird characters appear after writing to a textfile

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am currently trying to read a file, put extra backward slash () if it finds a backward slash, and write it to another file. The problem is, there are weird characters being printed inside the `path.txt`. I suspect that, the `space` characters from the file `logdata` is the root of this problem. Need advice how to solve this.

Here is the code:

```
// read a file
char str[256];
fstream file_op("C:\\logdata",ios::in);
file_op >> str;
file_op.close();

// finds the slash, and add additional slash
char newPath[MAX_PATH];
int newCount = 0;
for(int i=0; i < strlen(str); i++)
{
 if(str[i] == '\\')
   {
    newPath[newCount++] = str[i];
   }
   newPath[newCount++] = str[i];
}


// write it to a different file
ofstream out("c:\\path.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
out.write(newPath, strlen(newPath));
out.close();
```

Comment: Why are you opening a textfile in binary mode?

Comment: What is the maximum length of each string in a file?

Comment: Do you need to do it in C++? A script in sed, perl, awk, python, ... would be easier to write.

Comment: @space cowboy, is there any other opening mode? I just need to open the file to read the strings.  @maxim, I need to do it in visual c++.

Comment: The reading is fine. If you use an `ifstream`, you don't even have to specify `ios::in`. But you open the output file as binary, and then write text to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every char string in C has to end with character \0. It is an indicator that the string ends right there.

Your `newPath` array, after iterating through your for-loop is not correctly ended. It probably ends somewhere later, where \0 appears by accident in memory.

Try doing the following right after exiting the for-loop:

```
newPath[newCount]=0;
```

---

A safer way for using strings in C++, is to use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) class over plain char arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a string terminator in the buffer, after the loop :
newPath[newCount] = 0;